# addEventListener not working in angular select

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, dom-events

I am making a table using `primeng` and created table with three rows and three columns and every data is static..

Eventhough I have used external library, at the end I am trying to traverse the `DOM` only..

```
<p-table [value]="getData()">
      <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
    <th>Head 1</th>
    <th>Head 2</th>
    <th>Head 3</th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-car>
          <tr>
    <td>Data 1.1</td>
    <td>Data 1.2</td>
    <td><select><option>Select</option><option value="test1">Opt 1</option><option value="test2">Opt 2</option></select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 2.1</td>
    <td>Data 2.2</td>
    <td><select><option>Select</option><option value="test1">Opt 1</option><option value="test2">Opt 2</option></select></td>
  </tr>
          <tr>
    <td>Data 3.1</td>
    <td>Data 3.2</td>
    <td><select><option>Select</option><option value="test1">Opt 1</option><option value="test2">Opt 2</option></select></td>
  </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Now I am in the need to get the select box value of the selected item in the last column, for which I have written `addEventListener` like,

```
select.addEventListener('change', this.onclick.bind(this))
```

But it doesn't work.. The `onclick()` method doesn't triggers..

I think th eproblem might be due to `ngAfterViewInit` but if I give it inside `ngOnInit` the dom elements itself not accessible..

**Working Stackblitz:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tables-dhzmbt

Kindly help me to achieve the `addEventListener` in select box only using **pure JS/TS way** and template cannot be modified..

Comment: Why can't you use (click)="onClick()" at select element in the template?

Comment: @katzz0, That was the requirement given, I need to select dom elements then need to make addEventListener in typescript side alone as like I tried above.. Only thing I am in the need is to make work of the added event listener..

Comment: Add `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` into you component `metadata` for prevent rerender. Angular rerender view on every change detection cycle, i.e `DOM` unreliable between renders

Comment: @StasAmasev, Could you please help me to achieve the result through ```ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush``` and provide appropriate example..

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tables-d97kff?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

...

```
<td>
 <select(change)="onChange($event)>
  <option>Select</option>
  <option value="test1">Opt 1</option>
  <option value="test2">Opt 2</option>
 </select>
</td>
```

....

in the ts file

...

```
onChange(event) {
   console.log(event)
}
```

...

Comment: I have clearly mentioned in question that I cannot change anything in template.. Changes can be done only in ```.ts``` file..